# Как привязать колёсико мыши к полосе прокрутки в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Я написал класс полосы прокрутки, в котором я хочу привязать колесо мыши к полосе прокрутки, но всё безуспешно. Я попробовал задавать новое положение элементов(кнопок) и координаты самого ползунка, исходя от текущей Y координаты последнего элемента, но у меня выходит так, что ползунок идёт то очень быстро, то очень медленно. Так вот, я хочу чтобы, когда я прокручиваю элементы(кнопки) при помощи колёсика мыши, вместе с ним также двигался ползунок с элементами.

p.s. Я смотрел как это реализовано в pygame_menu и tkinter, но ничего так и не понял

Вот сам класс(он ещё толком не дописан, поскольку я наткнулся на эту проблему):

```
class ScrollBar:
VERTICAL = "Y"
HORIZONTAL = "X"

def __init__(self, screen, buttons: Button, direction, x=0, y=0, width=100, height=100, color=(105, 105, 105),
             slider_color=(50, 50, 50)):
    self.screen = screen
    self.buttons = buttons
    self.direction = direction
    self.BAR_X = x
    self.BAR_Y = y
    self.BAR_WIDTH = 20
    self.BAR_HEIGHT = height
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.color = color
    self.slider_color = slider_color
    self.SLIDER_WIDTH = 20
    self.SLIDER_HEIGHT = 20
    self.bar_rect = pygame.Rect(self.BAR_X, self.BAR_Y, self.BAR_WIDTH, self.BAR_HEIGHT)
    self.SLIDER = pygame.Rect(self.BAR_X, self.BAR_Y, self.SLIDER_WIDTH, self.SLIDER_HEIGHT)

#метод входа в класс
def pack(self):

    self.draw_bar()

    if not self.buttons is None and len(self.buttons) > 0 and self.buttons != []:
        for button in self.buttons:
            if button.y + button.height >= self.BAR_Y and button.y <= self.BAR_Y + self.height:
                button.draw(self.screen)

        if pygame.Rect(self.BAR_X, self.BAR_Y, self.BAR_WIDTH + self.buttons[0].width, self.height).collidepoint(*pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            self.scroll_mouse_wheel()
        self.scroll_bar()

def draw_bar(self):
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.bar_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.slider_color, self.SLIDER)

#сам скроллбар
def scroll_bar(self):
    MOUSE_CLICK = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    self.SLIDER_HEIGHT = (1 / len(self.buttons) if len(self.buttons) > 0 else 1) * (self.BAR_Y + self.height)
    if self.SLIDER_HEIGHT < 20:
        self.SLIDER_HEIGHT = 20
    self.SLIDER.height = self.SLIDER_HEIGHT

    if self.cursor_in_scrollbar():
        if MOUSE_CLICK[0] == 1:

            self.SLIDER.y = self.get_slider_y()
            speed_y = self.get_slider_speed_y()
            for i in range(len(self.buttons)):
                self.buttons[i].y = (i * self.buttons[-1].height) + self.BAR_Y - speed_y

def add_buttons(self, buttons: Button):
    self.buttons.extend(buttons)

def get_buttons(self):
    return self.buttons

#прокрутка элементов при помощи колёсика мыши
def scroll_mouse_wheel(self):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 4) or (
                event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP):
            self.move_buttons_up()
            #устанавливаю новое значение координаты Y для ползунка
            self.SLIDER.y = self.get_slider_y_for_mousewheel()

        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 5) or (
                event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN):
            self.move_buttons_down()
            #устанавливаю новое значение координаты Y для ползунка
            self.SLIDER.y = self.get_slider_y_for_mousewheel()

def move_buttons_up(self):
    for index, button in enumerate(self.buttons):
        button.y += button.height
        if index <= self.BAR_Y < button.y:
            for button1 in self.buttons:
                button1.y -= button1.height

def move_buttons_down(self):
    for index, button in enumerate(self.buttons):
        button.y -= button.height
        if index + 2 > len(self.buttons) and button.y + button.height < self.height:
            for button1 in self.buttons:
                button1.y += button1.height

#получаю новую Y координату для ползунка, если прокручивать при помощи мыши
def get_slider_y(self):
    return max(self.BAR_Y, min(self.BAR_Y + self.height - self.SLIDER.height, pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]))

#вот тут и находиться сама проблема, я не понимаю как рассчитать новую Y координату для ползунка
#мне толком не понятно, что взять для расчётов новой Y координаты для ползунка. Это или Y координата 
#первого или последнего элемента(кнопки), или вообще что-то другое
def get_slider_y_for_mousewheel(self):
    button = self.buttons[-1]
    return max(self.BAR_Y, min(self.BAR_Y + self.height - self.SLIDER.height, (self.BAR_Y + self.height) - (button.y + button.height) / len(self.buttons)))

#получение новой координаты для текущего элемента
def get_slider_speed_y(self):
    try:
        scroll_height = self.height - self.SLIDER.height
        scroll_rel = (self.SLIDER.y - self.BAR_Y) / scroll_height
        offset = (len(self.buttons) * self.buttons[-1].height - self.height) * scroll_rel
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        offset = 0
    return offset

def cursor_in_scrollbar(self):
    return self.bar_rect.collidepoint(*pygame.mouse.get_pos())
```

Правка 1:

```
def get_slider_y_for_mousewheel(self):
    button = self.buttons[-1]
    elements_on_screen = (self.BAR_Y + self.height) / button.height
    speed_y = (self.BAR_Y + self.height) - (button.y + button.height) * elements_on_screen / len(self.buttons)
    return max(self.BAR_Y, min(self.BAR_Y + self.height - self.SLIDER.height, speed_y))
```

Я чувствую что я на правильном пути, но всё же что-то не так. Элементы прокручиваются нормально вместе со скроллбаром, но он слегка не доходит до своей границы. Подскажите пожалуйста чему должно быть равно speed_y для корректной работы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос дублировался в английской версии и был решен, посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355902/tkinter-binding-mousewheel-to-scrollbar)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь товарищ! Оказывается tkinter не сильно отличается от pygame(по крайней мере по событиям). Там также есть такое поле у события как "delta", только называется оно по другому "y"